# call a DIV from my C# code behind

Tags: c#, html, css

I have been trying to call a DIV from my C# code behind...I have a conditional statement and if the condition passes then I need for the DIV to be called...the DIV will then trigger my CSS3 modal in my HTML....however...I can't seem to get the DIV Modal to fire...would someone be able to give me some advice???  Code is below...

I am new to C# so to many this may be a simple fix and a novice question...but I do appreciate your help...thank you...

HTML

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" name="last_name" runat="server" style="font-size:28px" class="content" placeholder="Enter Juror ID Number" maxlength="6" size="20" onfocus="jsKeyboard.focus(this);clean(this);" autofocus ontextchanged="IsValidNumber">

</asp:TextBox>
</div>


<center>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td><div class="juror_number_back_button_container">
<asp:Button id="Button1" 
           Text="Back"
           OnClick="Button1_Click" 
           runat="server" />
           </div>
</td>
    <td><div class="juror_number_continue_button_container">
<asp:Button id="Button2" 
           Text="Continue"
           OnClick="IsValidNumber" 
           runat="server" />
           </div>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</center>

<div id="feedback"></div>
<div id="virtualKeyboard">
</div>
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog" runat="server">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close"></a>
        <center><p class=" font_style_menu">Is this your Name and DOB?</p>
        <p class=" font_style_menu">John M Doe</p>
        <p class=" font_style_menu">7/12/1972</p>
        <p> <span style="font-size:30px">If No, please press No to Re-Enter Juror Number from your summons.</span></p></center>

<center>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>
<div class="modal_yes_button_container">
<form method="post" name="" action="checkin.aspx">
<input type="submit" name="Yes" value="Yes" />
</form>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="modal_no_button_container">
<form method="post" name="" action="#close">
<input type="submit" name="No" value="No" />
</form>
</div>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</center>
    </div>
```

C# Code Behind

```
protected void IsValidNumber(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      int num;

      if (Int32.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out num) && (TextBox1.Text.Length == 6))
      {
        DisplayDiv(true);
      }

      else
      {

        Response.Redirect("error_page_b.aspx");
      }
    }

    private void DisplayDiv(bool isShow)
    {
      openModal.Visible = isShow;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I would suggest either doing that with javascript or sometimes i cheat and surround my div in a label tag and call that from code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot use JavaScript patterns, you might consider the <asp:PlaceHolder></asp:PlaceHolder> control for that.

If you need to use a <div />, then put runat="server" on your div and make sure it has an ID.

```
<div runat="server" id="area"></div>
```

Comment: I have the DIV with a runat="server" and ID...the DisplayDIv function is supposed to be calling the DIV ID...but its not firing...do you see an error with the C# code I have?

Comment: Seriously, use a PlaceHolder if you can't use JavaScript/CSS patterns.

Comment: Thank you David...the placeholder is now firing the C# code behind and the DIV is now being called...now I just need to figure out why the Modal is not popping like it should...its almost like the CSS3 is not being called...any suggestions on that...if not I understand...I will keep working on it...but you have helped a huge amount..thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to make it visible by css (just don't hide it) and put the asp Visible attribute to false in the designer.

```
.modalDialog { /*display: none; */ }
```

Try also to change the Html div for an ASP Panel:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="openModal" CssClass="modalDialog" Visible="False">
```

Then your code will work.

Comment: PlaceHolder, not Panel. Panel is an obsolete ASP.NET 1.0 object that produces output; PlaceHolder has no output.

Comment: Panel is not obsolete: Supported in .NET Framework: 4.5, 4, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0, 1.1, 1.0. (source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel(v=vs.110).aspx). IIS renders the asp:Panel as your browser needs. In current browsers, it outputs a <div> that is what you write as answer.

Comment: It is obsolete, just not "deprecated"-- so it will always be there-- you don't "remove" things from a Framework. Use Placeholder-- as Panel adds its own HTML (read: is obtrusive).